# How to check person banning other person has high enough permissions?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I recently made a ban command to my discord bot butwhen my friend tried to ban me (he had permissions to ban but lower role) my bot sent out message that it has banned me but it of course didn't, is there a way to see if someone has a lower role than person that is supossed to be banned?
(I think that code would be useless so I will just say that my code checks for everything except this, if someone needs my code just ask, I will give it)

Comment: It's never a bad practice to show your code if you're asking programming-related questions, especially on SO. If we don't need it, we can just ignore it, while it only takes you a simple copy-paste.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the positions of the target and executer roles. For example add the check below. The `target` object must be a `guildMember`.

```js
if (message.member.roles.highest.position <= target.roles.highest.position) return message.reply('You can`t kick member with the same or highest role')
```

Answer (score 0):

In my bot, I have a line of code that outlines permissions like so:

```
if(command === "ban") {
  if(!message.member.roles.cache.some(r=>["RoleName"].includes(r.name)))
  return message.reply("You do not have permissions to use this command!");
```